# Env vars are undefined in Nextjs v12.0.8

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

I created a .env.local file and tried to console `process.env.TEST` (test env var) but I'm getting `undefined`. It seems `process.env` is always empty.
I restarted the server but I still don't see the env vars. I even tried to start a new empty project and `process.env` is still empty.

Am I missing something? All the other posts I see seem to have figured it out but I still can't.
My .env.local file is on the root level. I also tried to append the var with `NEXT_PUBLIC`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you show how your variables are defined and how you are using them in the code?

Comment: Inside .env.local: `TEST=testENV`

Comment: So it does not have any special symbols, just a string `testENV`? And how you are using them in the code then?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I ended up using the approach detailed in the accepted answer (next.config.js). I'm still not sure why .env.local doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, React env variables must be prefixed with `REACT_APP_` in order to be used with `process.env`. In the case of Next.js, you can put them in the `.env.local`, but they would **only be available in the Node.js environment**. If you need to make them available in the browser, you need to prefix them with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.
Refer to [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) for more details.

Another way (more old school Next.js) would be to have a `next.config.js` file.
A possible config would be:

```
const conf = {
  env: {
    myVar: process.env.MY_VAR,
  },
};

module.exports = conf;
```

Then you could simply use `process.env.myVar` inside your code. See [this page](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables) for more information.

Comment: The `REACT_APP_` mandatory prefix only applies to CRA, not to Next.js.